# How can I find out the native code of javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

When I type `setInterval` into google chrome's developer tools it writes the following to the console

```
function setInterval() { [native code] }
```

How can I find out the code that should be in `[native code]`?

Comment: you'll have to look into the javascript engine source code ;)

Comment: It's _native_ code. It isn't written in Javascript.  Read the V8 C source code.

Comment: It might be in here somewhere: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/

Comment: are you having a problem with setInterval? The typical usage is setInterval(function () {}, miliseconds)

Comment: Are you having trouble using `setInterval`, or are you simply curious about how your browser's JavaScript engine implements the [timers API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html)?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` is implemented by the rendering engine.

In Webkit/Blink it's a call to a [DOMWindow](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/page/DOMWindow.cpp) instance.

The most interesting bits are in [DOMTimer.cpp](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/page/DOMTimer.cpp)